# Django: Import legacy database data keeping primary keys having an autokey

Tags: django, django-models

I am using **Django** to develop new software to replace a legacy one, and all my new models have auto-increment primary keys. I want to import records from the legacy database keeping their original primary keys (users know them all), but I don't know how to do it with auto-increment primary keys.

Is it possible to create my models with integer primary keys and change them to auto-increment ones without losing their data?

Comment: It is possible to insert values into an auto-increment field. How are you exporting/importing the data? From one DB to another?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have an `IntegerField` as primary key without `auto-increment` feature. You can do this by

`id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary=True)`

And once you import all your data, you can convert it to `AutoIncrement` by replacing `PositiveIntegerField` to `AutoField`.

Solution-2

You can specify `id` of your row during data import while having default `AutoField` and it will load data properly. So no need worry here.

Comment: And, after replacing the IntegerField with AutoField, will it continue after the largest number used?

Comment: yes, It should. But you can verify and set it manually if it does not do automatically by `ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;`